# How can I split python codeblocks to a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an error checker. That gets all errors from code and I'll need to split codeblocks into a list and scan them one by one. Is there any module/builtin functions that can do the following thing?

I want to receive input as a code and output a list.

For example:

Input:

```py
while False:
    pass
def function():
    pass
print("Code sample")
for _ in range(1,100):
    for __ in range(_):
        pass
```

Output:

```py
["while False:\n    pass", "def function():\n    pass", "print(\"Code sample\")",
"for _ in range(1,100):\n    for __ in range(_):    pass"]
```

Comment: Not directly, but have a look at the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module. Also how are you planning to handle blocks inside other blocks, such as nested loops?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my question.

Comment: It might be beneficial to try and figure out how others have done this before you. Try researching how things like compilers (keep in mind python is not a compiled language though) and linters work. Also how python uses indentation levels.

Comment: So basically you want to split everything at top level? Can you think of a rule that tells you whether a given line of the input belongs in a new list item, or appended to the current one? Given that, can you think of a way to build the list by iterating over the lines of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `lib2to3.refactor.RefactoringTool` to parse the code using a fixer that is a subclass of `lib2to3.fixer_base.BaseFix` with a pattern that looks for the root node `file_input` and saves all its children in a list for later retrieval:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor

class SaveRootNodes(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = 'file_input'
    statements = []

    def transform(self, node, _):
        self.statements[:] = node.children

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, fixers):
        self._fixers= [cls(None, None) for cls in fixers]
        super().__init__(None)

    def get_fixers(self):
        return self._fixers, []
```

so that:

```
source = '''while False:
    pass
def function():
    pass
print("Code sample")
for _ in range(1,100):
    for __ in range(_):
        pass
'''

refactor = Refactor([SaveRootNodes])
refactor.refactor_string(source, '')
print([str(s) for s in refactor._fixers[0].statements if s.children])
```

outputs:

```
['while False:\n    pass\n', 'def function():\n    pass\n', 'print("Code sample")\n', 'for _ in range(1,100):\n    for __ in range(_):\n        pass\n']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FairReflectingExponent

`lib2to3` is round-trip stable so all comments and white spaces are preserved by the parser. You can find the definition of the Python grammar in [`Grammar.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt) of the `lib2to3` module.